# Excel 2016: if checkbox is true, copy value from one cell to another cell, if false, do nothing

Tags: checkbox, formula, excel-2016

Excel 2016:
I want to use a checkbox to copy the value from one cell to another cell.

Example:
I am using three cells: F36, G36, and H36.
The checkbox is in F36.
When checked (TRUE), I want the value in G36 ($350.00) to be copied to H36.
When unchecked (FALSE), do nothing.

I am already using conditional formatting for G36 and H36 to change text color depending on values.
I have tried using a formula to do this but to no avail. I have also searched YouTube and other forums for suggestions but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Excel's [Form Controls](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-check-box-or-option-button-form-controls-9f201e46-8f6b-4a9d-a320-f44b28088cb0) to add a checkbox, you can use an [`IF` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) in cell `H36` to do this:

`=IF(F36,G36,"")`

This formula states that if F36 is true (the checkbox is checked), `H36` should copy the value of cell `G36`. Otherwise, it shouldn't update.

*Checkbox is unchecked:*

[image: Excel screenshot of a checkbox in cell F36, the value "$350.00" in cell G36, and a blank cell, H36.]

*Checkbox is checked:*

[image: The same Excel screenshot as above, but the value "$350.00" is now in cell H36 instead of a blank cell.]

Comment: I tried you suggestion and it worked! Wow, it seems so easy. Thank you very much.